# Как поставить класс css по умолчению?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

Есть две кнопки - **Таблица** и **Список**. Нажимаю на **Таблица** - объекты выводятся таблицей. Нажимаю на **Список** - выводятся списком.

Все это дело запоминается с помощью `cookies`.
Проблема в том, что когда cookies пусты, то объекты отображаются в виде таблицы (это правильно), но по умолчанию активная кнопка **Список**
Получается мне нужно сделать один лишний клик. т.е. нажать на **Таблица**, она станет активной, но ничего не изменится т.к. объекты отображаются уже таблицей. И только потом на **Список**

Нужно чтобы объекты отображались таблицей и кнопка **Таблица** тоже была активной (класс `.active`)

**erb**:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="<%= 'active' if cookies['filter-product'] != 'buble' %>">
    <a class="nav-list" href="">item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if cookies['filter-product'] == 'buble' %>">
    <a class="nav-cols" href="">table</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- container with items -->
<div class="infinite-table">
  <ul class="ctf--b-product-list <%= 'product-list-buble' unless cookies['filter-product'] == 'buble' %>">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**js**:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $('.nav a').click(function() {
    if (!($(this).parent().hasClass('active')))
    {
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        if ($(this).hasClass('nav-cols'))
        {
          $.cookie('filter-product', 'buble');
          $('.ctf--b-product-list').addClass('product-list-buble');
        }
        else{
          $('.ctf--b-product-list').removeClass('product-list-buble');
          $.cookie('filter-product', 'non-buble');
        }
        return false;

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

css: (использую спрайты для кнопок **Таблица** и **Список**)

```
.nav { list-style:none; vertical-align:top; right:0; top:-50px; position:absolute; }
.nav li { float: left; padding:0 0 0 10px; }
.nav a { width:18px; height:18px; font-size:2em; line-height:0; display:block; }
.nav .active .nav-list { background-position:0 bottom; }
.nav .nav-cols { background-position:right 0; }
.nav .active .nav-cols { background-position:right bottom; }
```

или подскажите плагины для этих целей.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Поменять таблицу и список местами

Comment: в erb это понятно, иконки поменются местами и  отображаться будут правильно. Но логика не поменяется(кнопка **Таблица** будет выводить список). А вопрос скорее в js что поменять?

Answer (score 1):

Наверное так, если нет элемента с классом active, применяем этот класс на родителя класса nav-cols:
Можно еще объявить переменную в erb со значением из кук, и проверять если она есть то делать active исходя из условий, а если ее нет вообще то ставить active по умолчанию

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    if ( $('.active').length === 0 ) {
       $('.nav-cols').parent().addClass('active')
    }
    $('.nav a').click(function() {
    if (!($(this).parent().hasClass('active')))
    {
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        if ($(this).hasClass('nav-cols'))
        {
          $.cookie('filter-product', 'buble');
          $('.ctf--b-product-list').addClass('product-list-buble');
        }
        else{
          $('.ctf--b-product-list').removeClass('product-list-buble');
          $.cookie('filter-product', 'non-buble');
        }
        return false;

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
  });
});

<!-- container with items -->
<div class="infinite-table">
  <ul class="ctf--b-product-list <%= 'product-list-buble' unless cookies['filter-product'] == 'buble' %>">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: по умолчанию класс `.active` стоит на `nav-list` (в **erb** это первый тэг `li`), а я хотел бы поставить его по умолчанию на `nav-cols`. Если честно, всю голову сломал)

Comment: я не могу понять где  устанавливается класс `.active` по умолчанию

Comment: @dmitriy 2 3 и 4 строка в моем коде

Comment: да, спасибо. Это я понял. мне просто убрать нужно `.active` со **списка**. теперь эти кнопки обе активные. Поэтому и говорю, что не пойму где значение по умолчанию ставится